# Keyboard inputs to application using batch script

Tags: batch-file, batch-processing, batch-rename

Can any one help me to know how to give inputs to an application using batch script?

Explanation:

I have an application which enables logging when we press F1 key and disables logging when we press the Alt+L key from the keyboard. These key's only work when the application is in active state(Active in TaskBar)/ it is front in the screen. What i mean is we need give these inputs on that application.

Can any one help me with the batch script where the i can  enable logging it by pressing F1 and should disable it after 50 Sec by pressing the Alt+L on the active application window?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Batch can't. VBScript can

```
Set sh = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
sh.Run "notepad.exe", 9
WScript.Sleep 1000 'wait a while to load notepad app'
AppActivate "Untitled - Notepad"
sh.SendKeys "Hello World!"  
sh.SendKeys "{ENTER}"
WScript.Sleep 100'
sh.SendKeys "^p"

^=control
+=shift
%=Alt
{F1}=F1
%L=Alt + L
```